# No puedo leer las variables de sesión cuando paso de un arhivo a otro

Tags: php, html, cpanel

Tengo un problema con variables de sesión que no logro solucionar!.

Tengo dos archivos, uno es el validar_login.php y el otro es el index.php.

este es el validar_login.php:

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!$_POST){ session_destroy(); exit;}

    include 'configsql.php';

    $user   = $_POST["email"];
    
    if(!isset($_POST["password"])){ session_destroy(); exit;}

    $password = $_POST["password"];
    
    $queryusuario = ejecutarSQL::consultar("SELECT id_user FROM user WHERE correo='$user'");

    if (mysqli_num_rows($queryusuario) > 0) {
        

        while ($tipo = mysqli_fetch_array($queryusuario)) {
          
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
            $_SESSION['id'] = $tipo['id_user'];
            echo"<script>alert('".$_SESSION['loggedin']."')</script>";
            echo"<script>window.location.replace('../../pages/index.php'); </script> ";
            exit;
        }

    }else{
       echo "No existe el usuario.";
       session_destroy();
    }

?>
```

y  este es el index.php:

```html
<?php

if( !headers_sent() && '' == session_id() ) {
session_start();
}

echo"<script>alert('".session_save_path()."')</script>";

// Si el usuario no se ha logueado se le regresa al inicio.
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
    echo"<script>alert('".$_SESSION['loggedin']."')</script>";
    echo"<script>location.href='../../index.html';</script>";
    exit;
}
    
?>
```

El problema está en que la variable sesión $_SESSION['loggedin'] no contiene ningún valor en index.php, ¿puede que la sesión no se esté guardando o que se pierda?.

Answer (score 2):

Buen dia Jose Maria, intenta incluir en el archivo de index.php el validar_login.php puede que no lo este teniendo en cuenta y aqui sea donde se pierde las variables de sesión. De igual forma intenta con un var_dump validar en el index para ver que te esta pasando en las variables.

Comment: Buen día juan, muchas gracias por responder a mi pregunta. Juan aplico el var_dump y me sale que la variable "$_SESSION" es NULL. ¿Será porque no se está guardando?

Comment: agrega en el index el include 'validar_login.php'; de igual forma realiza la validación con el var_dump nuevamente. Y valida que no estes destruyendo la sesión como te dicen en los otros comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar var_dump al final de su archivo validar_login.php sobre la variable de sesión  `var_dump($_SESSION)`.

Tenga cuidado que no se este ejecutando algun session_destroy() inesperado ya que  borrara todos los datos de session.

Comment: muchas gracias por responder a mi pregunta. Aplico el var_dump y me sale que la variable "$_SESSION" es NULL. Creo que la sesión no la está guardando.

Comment: trate de debugear poco a poco con var_dump las lineas y vea en que punto se pierde el valor.